# Catkin_make fails with "ImportError: cannot import name ensure_workspace_marker"

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Under ROS hydro, catkin_make has been working fine for me.  However, now when I change to my local workspace and execute catkin_make, I get the following error:

```
~/catkin_ws $ catkin_make
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/bin/catkin_make", line 15, in <module>
    from catkin.builder import cmake_input_changed
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/builder.py", line 61, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.workspaces import ensure_workspace_marker
ImportError: cannot import name ensure_workspace_marker
```

A few days ago there was a massive upgrade of packages for ROS hydro which I installed, but I'm not sure if that is related or not.

What might have broken with my ROS installation that is causing this error?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181910/catkin_make-fails-with-%22importerror:-cannot-import-name-ensure_workspace_marker%22/) by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure this is the cause of your issue, but thought I'd report my experiences anyway:

I've seen this error popup on systems that had multiple installations of `python-catkin-pkg`. Most of the times these systems had the binary debian ánd a from-source version installed (through `pip`). The `pip` versions were in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/..`, with the debian packaged ones being in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/..` (note the `local`).

Manually removing all `catkin-pkg` related files and directories under `/usr/local/lib/..` and reinstalling the `python-catkin-pkg` got things working again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mpthompson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3684/mpthompson/) on 2014-07-01**:
Thank you very much. That is indeed the problem I ran into.  The following command worked for me to remove the older version of catkin-pkg that I must have installed at sometime with pip: "sudo pip uninstall catkin-pkg" This allowed the binary debian package to then be found and catkin_make was again happy.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-01**:
Great. I used pip first, but it didn't succeed in actually removing the package. Manual 'intervention' was my only option :).

**Comment by [RokusO](https://answers.ros.org/users/19667/rokuso/) on 2014-07-10**:
I did this, but when I try to reinstall python-catkin-pkg using apt-get, no packages are installed as it "is already the newest version". How can I fix this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-11**:
Are you sure you are RE-installing, not just installing? To reinstall using apt-get: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-catkin-pkg`.

**Comment by [RokusO](https://answers.ros.org/users/19667/rokuso/) on 2014-07-11**:
Thanks, you're right, I was just installing. However, this didn't help me. I probably had a different problem to begin with. I was stupid enough to actually rm the files you referred to in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. Is there a way to fix that?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-13**:
Just reinstall the packages? Reinstalling should put the files back.
Edit: did you remove everything under `dist-packages`? In that case you'll have to reinstall all python packages. That is probably easier to do with synaptic, but you could do smthing like `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python*`

**Comment by [RokusO](https://answers.ros.org/users/19667/rokuso/) on 2014-07-14**:
I tried reinstalling the packages using synaptic and apt-get, but both did not do the trick. Just to try, I installed the packages using pip, and now catkin_make is working again, but now roscore and roslaunch don't work anymore...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-18**:
@RokusO & @liat: I'm afraid I don't have any more advise to give, the above steps fixed everything for me. As a quick-stop measure: remove and then reinstall everything in python related to ROS (catkin-pkg, wstools, etc). Be sure to clean out any `/usr/local/..` files you find, then reinstall.